# Automatically create SQL Server local databases in other projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have 3 projects in a single solution that uses local SQL Server database file (`.mdf`) from one project. I have referenced the project that contains the SQL Server `.mdf` file from the other two projects. Also set to copy if newer for the `.mdf` file.

When the project runs all the 3 projects create their own `.mdf` files in `App_Data` folder. Is there way that I can use single local database? Also when the solution runs `.mdf` must be exist in the specified path as in copy if newer.

Comment: SQL Server is not a shared file database, its a server/service based database.

Comment: Are you talking about three separate web apps? The idea of a local data file is that it's local to the application. If there are three separate applications then using local data files should require three separate local data files. If you want three applications to use the same database then it shouldn't really be a local database but a permanently attached database. You could use a file in a common location but if multiple apps try to attach the data file to the instance at the same time then some will fail.

Comment: You can put the `.mdf` file in a folder outside the project on the solution level and can do the symbolic link to `App_Data` folder of each folder. That way all the project will point to same `.mdf` file. To create symbolic link you can refer this link https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/